# How to find all duplicates in a link table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with these columns:

```
1. ID_Table1
2. ID_Table1LinkTable2
3. ID_Table1LinkTable2
```

I need to find all duplicates by columns `ID_Table1LinkTable2, ID_Table1LinkTable2`

And drop these rows.

How can I do that?

Thanks for advance

As example I have

```
ID_Table1  ID_Table1LinkTable2 ID_Table1LinkTable2
--------------------------------------------------    
     1            123                   322
     2            123                   432
     3            123                  3432
     4            123                   322
```

I need to drop last row

Comment: Do you want to drop *all* rows that contain the duplicated values, or 
*all but one* of each duplicate so that the resulting table contains no duplicates?

Comment: Fields number 2 and 3 have same names, is that a typo?

Comment: I want to keep only one duplicate

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
delete from yourtable
where ID_Table1 not in 
(select MIN(ID_Table1) from yourtable group by ID_Table1LinkTable2, ID_Table1LinkTable2)
```

Answer (score -2):

`ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE(ID_Table1)`

`ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE(ID_Table1LinkTable2)`

This will delete the duplicates.